# Install Shield Limited EditionのFIesで相対パス指定することは可能ですか？

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2013においてInstall Shield Limited Editionを使ってinstallerを作成しています。

プライマリ出力などは問題無いのですが、Filesで任意の位置にfileを配置しようとした所、格納元のfileが絶対pathで定義されてしまいます。
単純にinstallerを作っている時は良かったのですが、svnから任意の位置にcheckoutしたりすると絶対pathが問題となり、installerのbuildでfileが見つからないとerrorになってしまいます。
絶対pathなので別のpathにcheckoutすればそうなるのは当然なんですが、相対pathで定義できれば問題無いような気がし、isl file内の定義を相対pathにしてみたりしたんですが、ダメでした。

Limited Editionでは、file pathの指定に相対pathは使えないんでしょうか？
可能であるならば、islの書き換え方がまずかったんでしょうか？
一応、isl fileの位置をcurrentとして、相対pathを記述してみました。

何か解決策があると嬉しいのですが...

---

参考までに添付したいfileのpathを記載します。

> svn_co_dir
>    ├ 添付file用dir
>    └ VSソリューションdir
>    　├ Windowsアプリケーションproject
>    　└ InstallShieldLE project
>    　　└ isl file

添付file用dir配下にいくつかのfileがあり、それをinstallerに格納、配置させたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

islファイルのあるフォルダを`<ISProjectFolder>`で参照できます。つまり、
　`<ISProjectFolder>\..\..\添付file用dir\ファイル名`
のようにすれば相対パスで参照できます。
ただし、islファイルはXMLファイルであるためタグを実体参照に置換して
　`&lt;ISProjectFolder&gt;\..\..\添付file用dir\ファイル名`
と記述します。

なお、参照に失敗するとファイル一覧のModified列に***File Not Found***と表示されるので確認可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。
なるほど、ISのショートカットを使えば良かったんですね...完全に忘れていました。確か他にもショートカットタグがあったと思うので、自分でも色々調べてみようと思います。